# Pro license on new install

Tags: craft-pro, license

I'm starting an existing CraftCMS site from scratch, but I will be using the same pro license I already own. Can I install that in the new install? Or dow I just transfer that license when I relaunch the site?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an existing Craft license for a new install – assuming it's not currently in use by a different site in production, of course.

You'll need to

a) Change the license's domain to the new production domain via your account on https://id.craftcms.com

b) Copy over the `license.key` file to your new project's `config` folder. Alternatively, put the key in your `.env` file and set it via the [`CRAFT_LICENSE_KEY`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#craft-license-key) PHP constant.

c) Optionally/ideally, clear Craft's data caches.

You'll find links for downloading or copying the license on `id.craftcms.com`, same place as you change the domain.

[More info about Craft licenses here](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/more-information-than-you-require-about-craft-license-keys).